# Does ksh88 interpret a number as decimal using 10#n syntax?

Tags: ksh

I would like to treat a number with leading zero as a decimal with the least effort
so I intend to use the following syntax:

```
x=08
y=$(( 10#$x - 1 ))
```

Will the following syntax work on **ksh88**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears so:

```
$ command -v ksh
/usr/bin/ksh
$ what /usr/bin/ksh
/usr/bin/ksh:
        Version M-11/16/88i
        SunOS 5.8 Generic 110662-24 Apr 2007
$ ksh

$ x=08
$ y=$(( 10#$x - 1 ))
$ echo "$x - $y"
08 - 7
```

From the "Arithmetic Evaluation" section of the [man page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html):

> Constants are of the form [ *base#* ] *n* where
>   *base*   is  a  decimal  number  between  two  and  thirty-six
>   representing the arithmetic base and *n* is a number  in  that
>   base.  If *base* is omitted then base 10 is used.